# Single *.feature or Scenario in *.feature fails with NoClassDefFoundError in serenity-cucumber-archetype

Tags: cucumber, noclassdeffounderror, thucydides

I'm using **serenity-cucumber-archetype** project and run it in different ways (in pom I specified *firefox* as webdriver.driver and in serenity.properties -> *chrome* as webdriver.driver):
1. using test runner, which successfully runs the tests in Chrome

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features/consult_dictionary/LookupADefinition.feature")
public class DefinitionTestSuite {}
```

2. using mvn site, which successfully runs the tests in Firefox
3. BUT, when I run separately *.feature file or single Scenario from *.feature file I get exception in run log:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter
   ```

Please advise, how to fix it and to make it possible to run single Scenario or single *.feature file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ and Cucumber v2.x:
You might need to upgrade IntelliJ, and/or the Cucumber-for-Java plugin. 
If that doesn't work, try uninstalling/installing the plugin.
Bachground:
There are changed to the Cucumber event model as of Cucumber v2.x and the Cucumber-for-Java plugin has been updated for those.